# Unable to edit list after converting from tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I'm using the code below:

```
a = ('Monty Python', 'British', 1969) #a is a tuple
b=list(a) #this should convert it to a list if I'm not wrong
print(b) #the output till here is okay
c=b.append("abcd") 
print(c) # the output for this is None
```

Can anyone explain why am I unable to edit after converting the tuple to a list??

Comment: `append` is an inplace operation.

Comment: `append` doesn't return the output list. It modifies the old one.

Comment: For the same reason as if you had a list in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.append()` does not return a list.

You are doing `c = b.append("abcd")`, this makes no sense because `b.append()` does not return a list, it returns none.

Try `print(type(b.append("abcd")))` and see what it prints. So as you can see python is working correctly.

Things like `.append() .pop()` do not return a new list, they change the list in memory.

This is called an inplace operation I believe

Comment: Thank you so much! I was assigning it so something else unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing c whose job is to append. Print b instead, that's your list.

Comment: Thank you for that! It helped